# how to calculate what is date after 10 days in php?

Tags: php, date, strtotime

Suppose the `$start_date = 2017-12-13`.

And i want to know what should be date after 10 days.

i tried this `strtotime("$start_date +10 days")` and the output is `1512946800`

Comment: $new_data = date('Y-m-d',1512946800);

Comment: Thanks buddy @Farhan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got the timestamp as value, now you just need to format it back to date.

```
date("y-m-d HH:mi:ss", strtotime("$start_date +10 days"))
date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$end_date -10 days")); //for minus
```

That should take care of it.

Comment: why all the updvotes? the format is wrong, `yyyy-mm-dd HH:mi:ss` should be `Y-m-d H:i:s`

Comment: @musashii It's a common thing here. People upvote what they think they see, not what they actually see.

Answer (score 3):

Why not using [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php#example-2528) ?

```
$start_date = "2017-12-13";
$date = new DateTime($start_date);
$date->add(new DateInterval('P10D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
```

outputs

> 2017-12-23

[demo](https://eval.in/919603)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo  date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+10 days", strtotime($start_date)));
```

You try like above. Replace from "+10 days" to your desired value to get the number of days added as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

use php `strtotime()` function to get the date after 10 days. the `strtotime()` function it give the unix timestamp of the future date, now format it using `date()` function as

```
$start_date = "2017-12-13";
$future_date =strtotime("$start_date +10 days");//it will give the unix timestamp of the future date, now format it using date() function as
$future_date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $future_date);
```

Check the mannual here [php strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 1):

Using DateTime its much easier

```
$start_date = "2017-12-13";
$date = new DateTime($start_date);

echo $date->modify('+10 day')->format('Y-m-d');
```